# Replace words from a text by words contained in other file's columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I'm trying to replace words that are in one column with others that are in another column in a large text.

Data:

> tables and the chairs are broken
>
> children are playing in the street
>
> I have a lot of cats.

Text columns

> abbreviate,abbreviates
>
> table,tables
>
> chair,chairs
>
> be,are
>
> lose,losing
>
> break,broken
>
> child,children
>
> play,playing
>
> cat,cats
>
> moonlight,moonlighted

```
import csv

with open('data.csv', 'r') as file, open('text-columns.csv', 'r') as columns:
    text = csv.reader(file)
    text_csv = csv.reader(columns, delimiter = ',')

    for rows in text_csv:
        new_rows = ','.join(word for word in rows)

        for lines in text:
            new_lines = ''.join(line for line in lines)

            for elements in new_rows:
                new_text = new_lines.replace(elements[1], elements[0])

                print (new_text)
```

**Good output:**

> **table** and the **chair** **be** **break**
>
> **child** **be** **play** in the street
>
> I have a lot of **cat**.

My output:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "l.py", line 15, in
>
> new_text = new_lines.replace(elements[1], elements[0])
>
> IndexError: string index out of range

Comment: `new_rows = ','.join(word for word in rows)` does not do what you believe it does. `word` is not what you think it is. Print it and you'll see.

Answer (score 1):

This is one approach.

**Ex:**

```
import csv

with open('data.csv', 'r') as file, open('text-columns.csv', 'r') as columns:
    text_csv = csv.reader(columns, delimiter = ',')
    text_csv = list(text_csv)

    res = []
    for row in file:
        if row:
            for checkVal in text_csv:
                if checkVal[1] in row:
                    row = row.replace(checkVal[1], checkVal[0])
            res.append(row)

with open("out.csv", 'w') as file:
    for row in res:
        file.write(row)
```

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't work. I had same problem :-( 
**Output: **
table ahahave the chber be breakn
chewillolhahave be plie in the street
I hahave a lot of cat.

Comment: It is working fine for the given example. Can you provide an example content that does not work so I can test?

Comment: Thanks but here doesn't work :(
**Output**
**First sentence:** table ahahave the chber be breakn
**Second sentence:** chewillolhahave be plie in the street
**Third sentence:** I hahave a lot of cat.

It works for a few words, but the others get very strange. Thank you for your help.